# In smarty, how to check whether an associative array is empty or not?

Tags: php, smarty

I done google for it, but couldn't get the correct solution. Can any one help me out to check whether the associative array is empty or not. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm hard pressed to believe you put "smarty array empty" in google and couldn't find an answer? try some of the hints on the first result, like `!$array` or `$array|@count == 0`, depending on if you array can be something other then empty or an array, and you want to check for that as well..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Smarty3, you can use [PHP's empty() function](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php):

`somefile.php`

```
<?PHP
$smarty->assign('array',array());
$smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

`template.tpl`

```
{if empty($array)}
  Array is empty
{else}
  Array is not not empty
{/if}
```

Outputs `Array is empty`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `Smarty` just check if array exists. For example

`somefile.php`

```
<?PHP
$smarty->assign('array',array());
$smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

`template.tpl`

```
{if $array}
  Array is set
{else}
  Array is not set
{/if}
```

Outputs `Array is set`.

While in php...

```
<?PHP
$array = array();
if($array){
  echo 'Array is set';
}else{
  echo 'Array is not set';
}
```

outputs `Array is not set`.

To solve this, i made a little workaround: created a modifier for smarty with the following code:
`modifier.is_empty.php`

```
<?PHP
function smarty_modifier_is_empty($input)
{
    return empty($input);
}
?>
```

Save that snippet in your `SMARTY_DIR`, inside the `plugins` directory with name `modifier.is_empty.php` and you can use it like this:

`template.tpl` ( considering using the same `somefile.php` )

```
{if !($array|is_empty)}
  Array is not empty
{else}
  Array is empty
{/if}
```

This will output `Array is empty`.

A note about using this modifier agains using `@count` modifier:
`@count` will count the amount of elements inside an array, while this modifier will only tell if it is empty, so this option is better performance-wise

Answer (score 0):

You can put the variable directly in an if-statement as long as you're sure it'll be always set (empty or not) like so `{if !$array}`. If you're looking for something akin to a ternary operator you could use variable modifier called [default](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.default.tpl) eg. `$array|default:"empty"`. There's also some help [in smarty docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/tips.tpl) and on their [forum](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=300&sid=01b54b7b761b55cd7215617adc92ab39). Using PHP's empty also worked for me.